# Shellscript send a message to a socket

Tags: bash, shell, sockets, sh

I want to send message to this local port in my system. Is it possible to send it without using nc(netcat) ?

I already tried the below, it did not work with the below error:

[image: Netstat output and error message while using exec and fd]

Comment: Pick bash *or* sh for your question's tag. They're different shells, and `/dev/tcp` is bash-only (not all copies of bash support it, either; it's a compile-time option whether to include support, so if you're using a copy of bash bundled by your OS vendor, they're the ones making the decision).

Comment: Why are you avoiding netcat?  POSIX shell is all about making it easy to call subprocesses.  Don't get sucked into the trap of avoiding fork+exec when it's the best way to do something.

Comment: This is an Embedded device and the OS supports basic sh only. We cannot use apt-get to install nc. But since it supports exec, i was trying something like this in the adb shell. Let me know if there is a way to achieve this in my embedded device. - sibi